# ValueError: array is too big - cannot understand how to fix this

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, csv, numpy

I run the following code :

```
traindata = trainData.read_csv('train.tsv', delimiter = '\t')
```

which calls this function :

```
def read_csv(self, filename, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"'):
    # open the file
    reader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter = delimiter, quotechar = quotechar)
    # read first line and extract its data 
    self.column_headings = np.array(next(reader))
    # read subsequent lines
    rows = []
    for row in reader:
        rows.append(row)
    self.data = np.array(rows)
    self.m, self.n = self.data.shape
```

This would then allow me to call

```
m, n = traindata.data.shape
print m, n, traindata.column_headings
```

Unfortunately, in my call to the `read_csv` function I get the error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-1cc5776f9a9c> in <module>()
     13 print "loading data.."
     14 
---> 15 traindata = trainData.read_csv('test.tsv', delimiter = '\t')
     16 
C:\pc in read_csv(self, filename, delimiter, quotechar)
     17         for row in reader:
     18             rows.append(row)
---> 19         self.data = np.array(rows)
     20         self.m, self.n = self.data.shape
     21 

ValueError: array is too big.
```

How can I fix this behaviour and allow the code to run?

Edit : The data is a .tsv file, [extract here.](http://pastebin.com/w9tc7tHZ)

Comment: How big is your file? What is the `len` of `rows`? You may need to split your data up or use something like pytables or pandas if it's too big for numpy to do in one go. Your data definitely looks like it could be put in a database of some kind.

Comment: @jozzas 21MB, 7395 rows of 27 columns. I thought numpy would handle these larger values?

Comment: Can numpy load your extract, or does it only fail on the full file?

Comment: @jozzas It will only fail on the full file, but I can't see any way around it :(

Comment: Try using `dtype=object` in your array call: `self.data = np.array(rows, dtype=object)`. Numpy is trying to create some very big strings that it doesn't need to - this keeps them as referenced python objects.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much. If you want to reframe your comments as a question I will accept your answer straight away. If you could include a really brief explanation on the reason for this fixing the issue I'd be really interested to read it too. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Numpy is creating an array of huge strings, each with a length set to the maximum length of any one string in that column, and you are probably running out of ram in the middle of this massive memory allocation.

By doing

```
self.data = np.array(rows, dtype=object)
```

numpy doesn't need to allocate big chunks of new memory for string objects - `dtype=object` tells numpy to keep its array contents as references to existing python objects (the strings already exist in your python list `rows`), and these pointers take up much less space than the string objects would.